# Can't resolve 'fs', when i install nodemailer inside nexjs 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modulenotfounderror, next.js14

my nextjs 14.1.0 app was working fine but then i install nodemailer for sending email for user registration purpose, but suddenly i got error of "fs" module. it was like :

**⨯ ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/dkim/index.js:10:11
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'**

i've also done some changes in my next.config.json file , does it responsible for that error ?

my next.config.json file looks like this :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: { serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose", "axios"] },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
    config.ignoreWarnings = [
      { module: /node_modules\/node-fetch\/lib\/index\.js/ },
      { file: /node_modules\/node-fetch\/lib\/index\.js/ },
    ]
    return config;
  },
};

export default nextConfig;
```